# shrink (truncate) file from beginning on linux

Tags: file, truncate, shrink

Is it possible in Linux (and/or on other Unix) 'shrink' file from beginning? I'd like to use it for persistent queue (no existing implementation suits my needs). From end of file I guess it's possible with truncate().

Comment: I started googling 'truncate beginning' after I wrote this post and it seems it isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ext4, xfs or some other modern file system, since Linux Kernel 3.15 you can use:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int fallocate(int fd, int mode, off_t offset, off_t len);
```

with the `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE`  flag.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man2/fallocate.2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try dropping half of logs using ex, but it is not as fast as I would like (5GB of logs takes ages):

```
ex -s -c "1d$(( $(wc -l /var/log/messages | awk '{ print $1 }') / 2 ))|x" /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use `cut` or `tail` to remove portions of a file.

`cut -b 17- input_file`
`tail -c +17 input_file`

This will output the contents of input_file starting at the 17th byte, effectively removing the first 16 bytes of the file.  Note that the `cut` example will also add a newline to the output.

Comment: I was interested in efficient in-place update of file through some system call. What you suggest is not it.

Comment: In that case, you could look at the system calls that the above commands are doing via `strace` and only do the 'meat' of the operation and not all the command line parsing, etc.